# Using "in all sorts of unexpected ways" for something that happens once to someone

Tags: idiom-request

I am not sure if we can use the expression "in all sorts of unexpected ways" when we talk about something that can only happen once to a living thing. Is there any other similar expression we can use instead?

For example:

> The cow warned "It's a place where you get killed in all sorts of
>   unexpected ways" to its friend as they were headed towards the
>   slaughterhouse.

Comment: *You* should not be taken as the addressee here (who indeed can be slaughtered in a variety of ways) but as the generic referring to all cows. In any case, this seems to strain at a semantic gnat while swallowing talking cows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for both of these to be true at once.

- X can happen to you only once.
- There's many ways X can happen.

Just because there's many ways X can happen, it doesn't mean all those ways have to happen at the same time.